# ReactJS check database for changes and update component without refreshing browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble figuring out how I can update the component with the new data from the database after the edit function has been run and the update to the database was successful.

I have tried doing `this.forceUpdate()` but that doesn't work. I heard about using `this.setState()` but I don't know how I would update it using that with the database as my classroom state is a JSON array.

I have been thinking and google-ing long and hard for days without any luck, so any advice or help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I am using MySQL for my Database. I don't know if that matters.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggle: false,
      toggleIdxArray: [],
      classroom: [],
      childflagged: '',
      flagreason: '',
      id: ''
    };
    this.eventHandler = this.eventHandler.bind(this);
    this.logChange = this.logChange.bind(this);
    this.handleEdit = this.handleEdit.bind(this);
  }

  logChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  }

  handleEdit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var data = {
      childflagged: this.state.childflagged,
      flagreason: this.state.flagreason,
      id: this.state.id
    }
    fetch("/classroom/edit", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw new Error("Bad response from server");
      }
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
      if (data.affectedRows === 1) {
        console.log('Edited Flag!'); //UPDATE COMPONENT FUNCTION OF SOME-SORT HERE
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    });

  }

  eventHandler(event, idx) {
    let updatedArr = this.state.toggleIdxArray.slice();
    let checkIdx = updatedArr.indexOf(idx);
    if (checkIdx === -1) updatedArr.push(idx);
    else updatedArr.splice(checkIdx, 1);
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        toggleIdxArray: updatedArr
      })
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/classroom")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(classroom => this.setState({ classroom }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <h1>Classroom</h1>
                    {this.state.classroom.map((classroom, idx) =>
                        <div className="child" key={classroom.id}>
              <p className="detail">Child's Name: <span className={classroom.childflagged}>{classroom.childsname}</span> <i title={classroom.flagreason} className={'fa fa-flag flag' + classroom.childflagged}></i><i title={classroom.starreason} className={'fa fa-star star' + classroom.starstudent}></i></p>
              <p className="detail">Parent's Phone Number: {classroom.parentsnumber}</p>
              <div className="actionMenu">
                <button className="flags" id={classroom.id} onClick={e => this.eventHandler(e, idx)}>Edit Flags</button>
                <button className="results">View Results</button>
                <button className="profile">View Profile</button>
              </div>
              <div className="actionForm">
                <div>
                  <form id={"flagform" + classroom.id} className={this.state.toggleIdxArray.includes(idx) ? '' : 'hide'} onSubmit={this.handleEdit} method="post" autoComplete="no">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value={classroom.id} />
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.logChange} value={this.state.childflagged} name="childflagged" placeholder="Flag Type" />
                    <input type="text" onChange={this.logChange} value={this.state.flagreason} name="flagreason" placeholder="Reason For Flag" />
                    <input type="submit" onClick={() => this.state.id = classroom.id} name="submit" value="Save Changes" />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
                </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by using:

```
}.then((data) => {
      console.log('Update Complete');
      this.setState({ classroom: data })
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

If you get back the data in a useful format after updating it on the database, just use setState with that data:

```
handleEdit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var data = {
      childflagged: this.state.childflagged,
      flagreason: this.state.flagreason,
      id: this.state.id
    }
    fetch("/classroom/edit", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        //Aside: because of the way promises work, this is the correct way to throw the error. Doing this you can catch it in the "catch" callback
        Promise.reject(new Error("Bad response from server"));
      }
      return response.json();
    }).then((data) => {
      if (data.affectedRows === 1) {
        console.log('Edited Flag!'); //UPDATE COMPONENT FUNCTION OF SOME-SORT HERE
        //use data to set state
        this.setState({ classroom: data });
      }
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    });

  }
```

Comment: setState with data didn't work as the data is only a response from the MySQL Update function. I tried the second suggestion and it was an infinite loop of updating... within a second, react re-rendered the component about 15 times.

Comment: Also when I tried setState, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Comment: Fixed it, I used `(data) => {
      console.log('Update Complete');
      this.setState({ classroom: data })
    }`

Comment: @Julian I fixed my answer with your solution, thanks for sharing it

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the component re-render by calling `setState` inside your `handleEdit` function, after the request finished and data returned:

```
handleEdit(event) {
    ....
    fetch("/classroom/edit", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function(response) {
      if (response.status >= 400) {
        throw new Error("Bad response from server");
      }
      return response.json();
    }).then(function(data) {
      if (data.affectedRows === 1) {
        /** Calling setState here
         * For example, if the data return is a classroom object,
         * you can update the classroom property of the state to 
         * reflect it
         */
        this.setState({classroom:[...this.state.classroom, data.classroom]});
      }
    })
    ....
  }
```

Basically, a react component will re-render if:

1. Its props change.
2. Its `setState` function is called.
3. Its `forceUpdate` function is called.

More details about this topic can be found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: That didn't work as data doesn't contain a classroom object. The data being returned is just a JSON array from the response of the MySQL Update function.

Comment: It's an assumption, how you structure your data / parse your response doesn't affect React from trigger a new lifecycle and re-render the component accordingly when `setState` is being called.

Comment: Oh right, I get it now, so basically it could work if I restructured my data perhaps?

Comment: There is no problem with the way you structure your component, all you need is to pass the correct data to the component state's classroom attribute. You can test how it works by setting `classroom` to an empty array inside your `then` block.

Comment: I just tried that to see how it works (set the classroom to an empty array in the `then` block) and I got this error in the console: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at App.js:47`

Comment: Are you using `es6`, if yes, try using the arrow function with your `then` block

Comment: Yes, I have fixed it now, I used `(data) => {
      console.log('Update Complete');
      this.setState({ classroom: data })
    }`